# Python Subset pandas dataframe based on first n unique elements from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (df) with many subjects.

```
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                --------------  -----  
 0   subject               20640 non-null  object 

 1   block                 20640 non-null  int64
```

Say I want to subset the df with the first n unique subjects (keeping all rows for those n subjects). Is there an easy command to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filter first unique values with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
n = 10
df1 = df[df['subject'].isin(df['subject'].unique()[:n])]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df['subject'].isin(df['subject'].drop_duplicates().head(n))]
```

If need first unique consecutive values:

```
print (df)
  subject
0       a
1       a
2       b
3       f
4       d
5       g
6       a <-should be removed
7       b <-should be removed

n= 3
s = df['subject'].ne(df['subject'].shift()).cumsum()
print (s)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
Name: subject, dtype: int32

df1 = df[s.le(n)]
print (df1)
  subject
0       a
1       a
2       b
3       f
```